# Redirecting Subfolder to Subdomain with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want Redirecting Subfolder to Subdomain with htaccess

I have this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sitename.com[NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.sitename.com$1 [L,R=301]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/subfolder/(.*)$ http://subdomain.sitename.com/$1
```

but when redirect categories get link like this
http://subdomain.sitename.com/5/cat?c=5
it should become like this
http://subdomain.sitename.com/5/cat

this is the full htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^game-([0-9]+).html$ file.php?f=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.+?)/([a-zA-Z]+)?/?([0-9]+)\.html$ browse.php?c=$1&p=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.+?)?$ browse.php?c=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^profile/([0-9]+)/.+\.html$ profile.php?u=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^page/(.+)\.html$ page.php?p=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^scores/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)\.html$ scores.php?f=$1&p=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^game-[0-9]$ $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^game-[0-9]$ arcade/gamedata/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^g([0-9]+)/?$ links.php?a=short&f=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^tag/(.+?)(|/|/([0-9]+)\.html)$ search.php?t=$1&p=$3 [L]
</IfModule>
```

thanks